# Active record querying for children objects of multiple parent objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Let's say i have two models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Then assume I've created 2 posts with 3 comments each. Is there a query I can call on an AR relation of those two posts to grab all the comments that belong to those two posts?

I could do:

```
@posts = Post.where(id: [1,2])
@comments = []
@posts.each do |post|
  @comments += post.comments
end
```

But then it's not an AR relation, plus seems like this should be a simple query.

Is there anything like `@posts.comments`?

Comment: i imagine it's something really simple, but can't find the simple on the interwebs .. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question talks about "belongs to those two posts" but you're suggesting using `Post.all`, so it's not clear if you're after the comments for all posts, or just those two.

Here's how to get the comments for the two posts, say their ids are `1` and `2`:

```
Comment.where post_id: [ 1, 2 ]
```

...but if you don't know the IDs then you can use any query you like to return the posts you're interested in to create a sub-select, such as:

```
Comment.where post: Post.where(owner: owner)
Comment.where post: Post.where("title LIKE ?", "%abc%")
```

Alternatively you can use a join from comment to post like so:

```
Comment.joins(:post).where(posts: { owner: owner })
```

So there are some options for doing what I think you're asking.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear, really what I'm asking is there anything like `.comments` for a `Post` relation

Comment: `Comment.joins(:post)` is the closest thing, conceptually to a `.comments` for `Post`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a query I can call on Post.all to grab all the comments that belong to those two posts?

If you're just trying to get all comments that belong to a post do this

```
Comment.where.not(post_id: nil)
```

Comment: Depending on your DB constraints, it may still be better to `Comment.joins(:post)`, in case there are deleted posts with hanging keys left in `comments`